# How to run the information in the arrays through the respective Class

Tags: java

I am having trouble with the display print of the Employee and Executive class it is giving a weird output that is giving me issues resolving. ***** I have updated the code to correctly working code.....Thanks

```
public class Employee {

private String name;

private int salary;

public Employee(String nam, int sal) {

    name = nam;

    salary = sal;

}

double annualSalary() {

    return salary * 12;

}

public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("Name: %s%n", getName()));
    sb.append(String.format("Salary:  %s%n", getSalary()));

    return sb.toString();

}

public String getName() {

    return name;

}

public int getSalary() {

    return salary;

}

} 

class Salesman extends Employee {

int annualSales;

public Salesman(String nam, int sal, int annSales) {

    super(nam, sal);

    annualSales = annSales;

}

double annualSalary() {

    double commision, total;

    commision = (2 / 100.0) * annualSales;

    if (commision > 20000) {
        commision = 20000;
    }

    total = getSalary() * 12;

    total = total + commision;

    return total;

}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("Name: %s%n", getName()));
    sb.append(String.format("Salary:  %s%n", getSalary()));
    sb.append(String.format("Annual Sales:  %s%n", annualSales));

    return sb.toString();
}
}

class Executive extends Employee {

private int currentStockPrice;

Executive(String nam, int sal, int stprice) {
   super(nam, sal);
   currentStockPrice = stprice;
}

double annualSalary() {
    double total, commission;
    if (currentStockPrice > 50) {
        commission = 30000;
    } else {
        commission = 0;
    }
    total = getSalary() * 12 + commission;
    return total;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("Name: %s%n", getName()));
    sb.append(String.format("Salary:  %s%n", getSalary()));
    sb.append(String.format("Current Stock Prices:  %s%n", currentStockPrice));

    return sb.toString();
}
}

import java.io.*;

public class LoadData {

public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String workingdirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String fileName = workingdirectory + "/data.txt";
    File dataFile = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream dataFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataFileInputStream));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
        String parts[] = line.split("\\s+");
        if (parts[0].equals("2014")){       
            switch(parts[1]){
                case "Employee":
                    Employee emp = new Employee(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
                    System.out.println(emp.toString());
                    break;
                case "Salesman":
                    Salesman sales = new Salesman(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]), Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
                    System.out.println(sales.toString());
                    break;
                case "Executive":
                    Executive exec = new Executive(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]), Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
                    System.out.println(exec.toString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (parts[0].equals("2015")){       
            switch(parts[1]){
                case "Employee":
                    Employee emp = new Employee(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
                    System.out.println(emp.toString());
                    break;
                case "Salesman":
                    Salesman sales = new Salesman(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]), Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
                    System.out.println(sales.toString());
                    break;
                case "Executive":
                    Executive exec = new Executive(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[3]), Integer.parseInt(parts[4]));
                    System.out.println(exec.toString());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String tostring()
```

should be

```
@Override
public String toString()
```

Java method names are case-sensitive.

Also, you cannot reduce the visibility of a method you plan to override. (toString needs to be public, you made it the default package protected).

Also, you should include an `@Override` annotation when you override methods. (It isn't required for methods inherited from Object, but it is good practice.)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Those small errors can wreak havoc on outputs.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept if this answer is your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
public String toString() {
...
```

You have the error in your signature of method. Use the `@override` annotation to ensure the overriding method, in which you can help the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Much appreciated.